# jquery form helper - add more fields

Tags: jquery

I quickly made this form helper to walk a user through a sign up form

it works fine for name and username but im wondering how to expand it so that all fields are disabled apart from name to begin with.

Once name has a value, only username becomes enabled also (this works so far) then once username has a value, password will become enabled and so on.

The form fields are
name, username, password, password_confirm and email

here is the code

```
$(function() {
    var helper = function() {
        if ( $('#name').val() == "" ) {
            $('#username').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#helper').text("Hi there! let's start by entering your name!");
        } else {
            $('#username').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#helper').text("Great, now choose a username.");
        }
    };
    $('.input-xlarge').keyup(helper).change(helper);
});
```

cheers

Markup added

```
        <form class="form" method="post" action="sign_up.php" id="sign-up-form">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="name"><?php _e('Full name'); ?></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $signUp->getPost('name'); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Full name'); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group" id="usrCheck">
                    <label class="control-label" for="username"><?php _e('Username'); ?></label>                
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="username" name="username" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $signUp->getPost('username'); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Choose your username'); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password"><?php _e('Password'); ?></label>                
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" class="input-xlarge" id="password" name="password" placeholder="<?php _e('Create a password'); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password_confirm"><?php _e('Password again'); ?></label>              
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" class="input-xlarge" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="<?php _e('Confirm your password'); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="email"><?php _e('Email'); ?></label>              
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="email" class="input-xlarge" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $signUp->getPost('email'); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Email'); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <?php $signUp->profileSignUpFields(); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <?php $signUp->doCaptcha(true); ?>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['token']; ?>"/>
            <button type="submit" class="medium orange"><?php _e('Create my account'); ?></button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against disabling, in case they need to go back.

How about just doing something like this:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="name" title="do name"/>
<input type="text" id="username" title="do user"/>
<input type="text" id="tel" title="do tel" />
<input type="text" id="fax" title="do fax"/>

<div id="helper"></div>​
```

js:

```
function helper(e){

 var text = e.attr('title');
 $('#helper').text(text);

}

$(":input").click(function(){

    $(":input").css('background-color','#000000');
    $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
    helper($(this));

});
```

you can view the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Rzha3/3/

Comment: apologies, check my updated fiddle, I gave you a link from earlier on in the process. Reason was I had the helper function after the function was called, plus a syntax error! Sorry wrote it quickly before  left.

Comment: thats nice, cheers. 1 question how can i make it show the first input instruction on load as it only starts once the input is clicked

Comment: i made a change to use focus instead of click so it works if the user presses tab also. and added $("#name").focus(); to start it off

Answer (score 0):

In the form HTML, hard set all of the disabled attributes to disabled (or disable them all in $(document).ready(), so it's non-JS compatible). Then generalize your helper function to take a field as a variable, then get the next one in line. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Disable all input fields
    $('#myform input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    //Bind the helper function to input fields on keyup
    $('#myform input').keyup(function() {
        var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
        helper(this_id);
    });
    //Call helper on "username" to kick things off
    helper('username');
});

function helper(field_id) {
    var messages = new Array(/*messages stored here, starting with "Hi!" at 0*/);
    var field_index = $('#'+field_id).index();
    if ( $('#'+field_id).val() == "" ) {
        var message = messages[field_index];
        $('#helper').text(message);
    } else {
        var next_index = field_index+1;
        var new_message = messages[next_index];
        $('#myform input:eq('+next_index+')').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#helper').text(new_message);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, and it could probably be more eloquent, but you should put it in your own style anyway. I put all the inputs as children of the "myform" ID, but you could just use your "xlarge" class if it's exclusive to the form. Maybe you could have a global index pointer instead of fetching it from the ID every time, too.